# Vbscript Regular Expressions - Matching [nextpage]

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to take input from a CMS and turn it into multiple pages. How I'm going about this is trying to write a regular expression that extracts each "page" into an array by looking for **[nextpage]**. I can get really close, but the output isn't what I'm looking for.

**Assuming this content for example:**

We the People of the United States, in Order to form [nextpage] a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty [nextpage] to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.

**My current regular expression:**

```
/(.*?)\[nextpage](.*?)/
```

**My desired result:**

[0] = We the People of the United States, in Order to form

[1] = a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty

[2] = to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.

---

Thank You.

Comment: Try doing a global find using `(.*?)(?:\[nextpage\]|$)`

Comment: @sln, thank you, this seems to be producing nearly what I was looking for. One minor issue that I'm now having, is that example should have produced the above results, however there is always an empty result at the end.

I can deal with this with an if statement or adjusting my loop/count that isn't a problem, I just want to make sure I know why so I can plan for it or fix it. I even ran this pattern in PHP and I had the same issue, so I realized it wasn't my vbscript.

Thank You

Comment: Posted a fix in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this from my comment.

`however there is always an empty result at the end.`

Sure, the `.*?` allows for empty content between `[nextpage][nextpage]`.

If you want to lop off trailing blank, just use `(.*?)(?:\[nextpage\]|$)(?<=.)`

This also will fix the extra empty match at the end.

**Update for VBscript**

Apparently VBscript is the same junk as JScript.

In that case, you have to use this `(.*?(?=\[nextpage\])|.+)(?:\[nextpage\]|$)`

*Note - if you want the match to span lines, you would use `[\S\s]` in place of the dot `.` in the regex.*

`([\S\s]*?(?=\[nextpage\])|[\S\s]+)(?:\[nextpage\]|$)`

Comment: thank you, however instead of an empty match I get an error **Syntax error in regular expression**. Could there be an issue with this being a vbscript regexp vs another language?

Comment: so for the multiline, are you saying this would be the expression? Sorry, I don't use regex much:

([\S\s]*?(?=\[nextpage\])|[\S\s]+)(?:\[nextpage\]|$)

Comment: That looks right, don't forget to escape the square brackets. Formatting note: if you put backticks `\`` around your code blocks it makes it easier to read because it highlights and uses a fixed width font. `([\S\s]*?(?=\[nextpage\])|[\S\s]+)(?:\[nextpage\]|$)`

Comment: Also, depending on how you want to interpret the number of pages, _split_ may be more appropriate for you like @bgalea answer. Example: if `[nextpage]` is 2 pages or not.

Comment: thank you. I accepted your answer for a couple of reasons: It was was an answer to my specific question and it is more versatile.

Answer (score 3):

This seems easier.

```
Dim B
A = "Whereas the people of New South Wales, Victoria, South Australia, Queensland, and Tasmania, humbly relying on the blessing of Almighty God, have agreed to unite in one indissoluble Federal Commonwealth under the Crown of the United Kingdom [nextpage] of Great Britain and Ireland, [nextpage] and under the Constitution hereby established:"
B = Split(A, "[nextpage]")
Count = 0
For each term in B
    msgbox Count & " = " & term
    Count = count+1
Next
```